# google maps v2 draw polyline depends on speed

Tags: android, google-maps

i have this database:
[image]

and i've tried to make a simple polyline drawing which is depends on the speed this way:

```
Cursor curTAB = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM  GPS_Values;", null);    
Integer count = 0;
while (curTAB.moveToNext()) {
String s_latitude = curTAB.getString(1);
String s_longitude = curTAB.getString(2);
String s_speed = curTAB.getString(5);    
count++;    
double latitude = Double.parseDouble(s_latitude);
double longitude = Double.parseDouble(s_longitude);
int speed = Integer.parseInt(curTAB.getString(5).toString());
if (speed <= 50) {
Log.i("Coordinates",
 s_latitude.toString() + " --- " + s_longitude.toString() + " --- " +s_speed.toString());
line.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).color(Color.GREEN);
line.color(Color.GREEN);
map.addPolyline(line);
} else {
Log.e("Coordinates",
s_latitude.toString() + " --- " + s_longitude.toString() + " --- " +s_speed.toString());
line.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).color(Color.BLUE);
line.color(Color.BLUE);
map.addPolyline(line);
}
Log.i("Coordinates",
s_latitude.toString() + " --- " + s_longitude.toString() + " --- " +s_speed.toString());
}
curTAB.close();
myDataBase.close();  
double latitude = Double.parseDouble(first_lat);
double longitude = Double.parseDouble(first_long);map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,
longitude), 15));
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);
```

But every line is with the same color.
Please help me what did i wrong!

update:
the working code(at the last point it doesn't work but not a big problem)

```
Integer count = 0;
        while (curTAB.moveToNext()) {
            String s_latitude = curTAB.getString(1);
            String s_longitude = curTAB.getString(2);
            String s_speed = curTAB.getString(5);

            double latitude = Double.parseDouble(s_latitude);
            double longitude = Double.parseDouble(s_longitude);
            int speed = Integer.parseInt(curTAB.getString(5).toString());
            int position = curTAB.getPosition();

            count++;

            System.out.println("Curr     " + latitude + " --- " + longitude
                    + " --- " + speed);

            if (curTAB.moveToNext()) {
                String next_speed = curTAB.getString(5);
                String ss_latitude = curTAB.getString(1);
                String ss_longitude = curTAB.getString(2);
                System.out.println("Next     " + ss_latitude + " --- "
                        + ss_longitude + " --- " + next_speed);
                curTAB.moveToPosition(position);

                double n_latitude = Double.parseDouble(ss_latitude);
                double n_longitude = Double.parseDouble(ss_longitude);

                if (speed > 60) {
                    map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                            .add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                                    new LatLng(n_latitude, n_longitude))
                            .width(10).color(Color.RED));
                } else if ((speed < 56) && (speed > 31)) {
                    map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                            .add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                                    new LatLng(n_latitude, n_longitude))
                            .width(10).color(Color.GREEN));
                } else if (speed < 31) {
                    map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                            .add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                                    new LatLng(n_latitude, n_longitude))
                            .width(10).color(Color.rgb(255, 127, 80)));
                }
            }else{              
                System.out.println("VÉGE");
            }

            line.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the maps-android-API, but it looks as if you add a new Polyline for each db-entry which will have the same path as the polyline added before **plus** the new LatLng from the current entry.

The result will be that you only see the polyline created for the last entry which will cover all the other polylines.

I guess you need to set up a new PolylineOptions-object on each iteration and add as Points the LatLngs of the recent entry and of the current entry to get the desired result.